# Math formula to calculate game score

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am developing a mobile game, however I am a little stuck on the part where I need to calculate the players score. I need to come up with a formula to calculate that, and I need your help!

Here are the mechanics:

An object start moving at 3 km / h, and it can accelerate to 20 km / h.

An object needs to be launched before hitting the wall. You can only release the object when there are 15 meters left until the wall (all the way to the 0 meter left until the wall).

The general idea - the faster you go and the closer to the you launch it - the higher the score.

Few scenarios:

1) You are going 19 km / h and you launch the object 2 meters left until the wall

2) You are going 19 km / h and you launch the object 10 meters left until the wall

3) You are going 4 km / h and you launch the object 2 meters left until the wall

4) You are going 4 km / h and you launch the object 10 meters left until the wall

The SPEED is more important than distance to the wall

So in these 4 scenarios the highest score would be "1", then "2" (because they have had a higher speed), and then "3" and "4" would follow - they have lower speed, so we're looking to the meters left until the wall.

The lowest possible amount of this equation should be 0 (or 1), and the highest possible equation should be oriented to somewhere around 2000

That's the challenge I am facing, who's up for helping me solving me this puzzle? :)

Comment: To be perfectly honest I am mathematically retarded, so the description of the formula is as far as I have managed to go - figuring what is more important and what influences the end score. I have no idea how to turn this into the formula, otherwise I wouldn't have ended up here

Comment: 1. Don't be so hard on yourself! 2. What is the "resolution" of the possible speeds/distances? For example, can you only go 20 km/h, 19 km/h, ..., 3 km/h, *or* can you go 20.00 km/h, 19.99 km/h, 19.98 km/h, etc.? This amounts to being a discrete vs. continuous problem.

Comment: That's a good question!

To make the game score more dynamic I believe the best route would be to take the speed as 19.45 km / h (2 numbers after the comma), as well as the length left until the wall - 1.32 m instead of just 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Also, just to confirm your description of the rankings, it sounds like no matter what happens, a greater speed should always give you a higher score. And then (it seems) a lower distance would be used to rank all launches of the same speed? For example, if A shoots 19 km/h but releases poorly with 10 m from the wall, and then B shoots 18 km/h but releases well with 1 m from the wall, then you would still assign more points to A?

Comment: That is correct! The main objective of the game is to get a good acceleration - that is the key, and then try to launch the object as close to the wall as possible. So in your example you are right, even though 18km/h released the object very close to the way, the A was going faster, so the formula should give player A a higher score

Comment: Ok nice to clarify all that. I'm working on a model that can account for priority on speed then minimizing the distance. I'll formulate it so you can adjust various aspects about the problem (e.g., max score possible, min speed, max speed, min distance, max distance, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty formula would be:

$$S = \frac{100 v (15 - d)}{15},$$

where $S$ is your score, $v$ is the speed in km/hour, and $d$ is the distance in meters.  The closer you get to the wall, the closer the number in parentheses gets to $15$.  The speed acts as a multiplier, up to $20$.  So, if you are going $20$ km/hour and launch just before hitting the wall $d \approx 0$ then you should see a score of $100 \cdot 20 \cdot 15 / 15 = 2000$ points.

If you want to weigh speed more heavily, you can make it a quadratic dependence:

$$S = \frac{5 v^2 (15 - d)}{15},$$

With this scheme you still have a maximum of $2000$ points but the score is eight times higher going at $20$ km/h as it is going at $7$ km/h.

Comment: That's actually a really smart formula. Just I am trying to figure out whether this is actually fair in the players perspective.

Here's the quick calculations I did:

SPEED / LENGHT / SCORE

19 4 1393
19 13 253
4 3 320
4 12 80

Player number 3 was going only 4 km / h speed, but managed to launch object 3 meters to the wall, which wasn't very hard as he was moving rather slow

However Player number 2 got a lower score, because he launched the object further from wall - but was going much faster

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: For both equations try $(v,d)=(3,0)$ and $(v,d)=(4,10)$. Speed must have higher weight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another formula in which I consider score $S$ as a linear function of speed $v$ and distance $d$:

$$S = \frac { 1000 }{ 9 } \left( \left( \nu -3 \right) +\frac { 10-d }{ 11 }  \right) $$